# Какие есть открытые или бесплатные аналоги библиотеки libxl?

Tags: c, excel, поиск-библиотек

Есть потребность работать с файлами `excel` из кода на языке `C`. Приобретать библиотеку `libxl` не хотелось бы. Использую ОС `Windows` и компиляторы `MinGW`.

Есть ли альтернативы?

Я попробовал работать с аналогами, вроде `libxlswriter`, но существует ряд проблем: невозможность чтения из файла, проблемы с современными форматами таблиц и пр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть потребность работать с файлами excel из кода на языке C.

*libfreexl1* -  FreeXL is a C library implementing direct reading of Microsoft Excel
spreadsheets, up to the BIFF8 file format specification (i.e. .xls,
Microsoft Excel XP/2003 and older). The XML SS file format specification
(.xlsx, Microsoft Excel 2007 and newer) is not supported.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то это библиотека для считывания данных, но не для редактирования/создания. К тому же она не для `Windows`. Возможно, я ошибаюсь, найти более полную информацию не смог.

Comment: @MGNeo **не для Windows** - да, разумеется. Но можно попытаться взять исходный код с *https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/freexl/index* и подкрутить его под виндовоз. Там всего один файл. Правда, размер его - 120 кил. Кстати, в самом начале этого файла есть такая строка: *#if defined(__MINGW32__) || defined(_WIN32)*  Что наводит на мысли...